# Protection against constant overvoltage from power supply

Tags: circuit-protection, surge-protection, over-voltage-protection

- I have a project using USB VBUS as power source.
- Fault to protect from: a bad AC-DC 5V adapter goes haywire, or a USB form factor device with non-5V output (some laptop AC-DC with USB type C?), or power surge.

The first thing comes to my mind is crowbar:
[image]

- F1, D3, D5, R14, C14 is the crowbar, but I don't understand the function of C14.
- D1 protects from back-flow.
- C11 is the main power supply capacitor to provide AC filtration and power stabilization, D2 and R13 forms slow-charge-quick-discharge for C11 to prevent spike when the power is first connected.

Am I using the crowbar correctly? Do I need a TVS somewhere? Any suggestion / improvement is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A bad/haywire adapter could inject 20 amps at up to 250 volts. Is this the "threat" you wish to protect against? What is the potential victim you have in mind? Protection is a numbers game and not a guessing game.